# How do I fix extraDataValid error while trying to run a test program on a gem5 simple ARM configuration with cache?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, gem5

I am learning how to use gem5. I followed the learning_gem5 book and successfully ran the suggested test programs on an ARM simple configuration without cache. For my research, I need to test caches on ARM systems, so I tried to adapt the simple_cache.py file to run on ARM, like what was done to simple.py to generate simple-arm.py. However, when trying to run the "hello" test program, or the other two that were suggested in the "Extending gem5 for ARM" page, I get the following error:

```
gem5.opt: build/ARM/mem/request.hh:882: uint64_t gem5::Request::getExtraData() const: Assertion `extraDataValid()' failed.
Program aborted at tick 12162000
```

The full terminal log is available at https://pastebin.com/VLJ1Szxy.
The config file is available at https://pastebin.com/SeajkNPT.

I tried changing the test file to the Bubblesort and FloatMM files. I checked the request source code to try to understand more about the error. I expected the simulation to run like it did with simple-arm.py. I followed the tutorial on this page: https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/extending_configs

Comment: You'll likely have more success with this question by posting directly to one of the gem5 mailing lists https://www.gem5.org/mailing_lists/  I believe there is a gem5 Slack workspace which is good for quick questions and troubleshooting tips.